# Count values from a column

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to count distinct values in a column. Column contains data like this

```
Locations
Street1
Street2
Street3
Street1,Street2
Street2,
Street1,Street2,Street3
```

Now count should be like
Street1 (3)
Street2 (4)
Street3 (2)

Comment: Is it just comma-separated in the database? That's not going to make life easy...

Comment: wtf? what's your database? sql server or excel? :)

Comment: @RPM1984: The linq-to-sql tag indicates SQL Server.

Comment: @Ani - yes i know, it was a joke. :)

Comment: @RPM1984: Ah, I get it. Apologies, it appears I'm thick today. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way of doing this with LINQ to SQL.

An easy way of course (if you can afford to do it), would be to bring all the rows in the table back to the client and then do the querying with LINQ to Objects.

```
var query = myDataContext
           .MyTable
           .AsEnumerable()
           .SelectMany(row => row.Locations.Split(','))
           .GroupBy(location => location)
           .Select(group => new { Location = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });
```

If you want a sequence of *strings* instead in that format, replace the last line with:

```
.Select(group => string.Format("{0} ({1})", group.Key, group.Count());
```

---

On another note, I would *strongly* recommend normalizing your database schema. It isn't a good idea to store delimited lists in a column.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Locations
    .SelectMany(s => s.Split(','))
    .GroupBy(s => s, (loc,b) => new { loc, b.ToList().Count});
```